How to initialize a singleton with a model container in SwiftUI?
How do I initialize a singleton with a model container while keeping the ability to use @Environment(\.modelContext) private var context throughout my application?
Currently, I'm doing the following to initialize my model container:
import SwiftData


@main
struct MyApp: App {
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .modelContainer(for: [Observation.self])
    }
}

And my singleton is as so:
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData
import os

/// `DataStore` is an actor responsible for updating the SwiftData db as needed on the background thread.
private actor DataStore {
    let logger = Logger(
        subsystem:
            "com.cyrilzakka.MyApp.DataStore",
        category: "ModelIO")
    
    private let container: ModelContainer
    
    init(container: ModelContainer) {
        self.container = container
    }
    
    func update(newObservations: [ObservationWrapper], deletedObservations: [UUID]) async throws {
        let context = ModelContext(container)
        
        // [ObservationWrapper] -> [Observation]
        let modelUpdates = newObservations.lazy.map { sample in
            // [...] Conversion code
        }
        
        
        try context.transaction {
            for obj in modelUpdates {
                context.insert(obj)
            }
            try context.delete(model: Observation.self, where: #Predicate { sample in
                deletedObservations.contains(sample.id!)
            })
            try context.save()
            
            logger.debug("Database updated successfully with new and deleted observations.")
        }
    }
}

@MainActor
public class UserData: ObservableObject {
    
    let userDataLogger = Logger(
        subsystem:
            "com.cyrilzakka.MyApp.UserData",
        category: "Model")
    
    public static let shared = UserData()
    
    // MARK: - Properties
    public lazy var healthKitManager = HKManager(withModel: self)
    
    let modelContainer: ModelContainer
    private var store: DataStore
    
    private init() {
        do {
            modelContainer = try ModelContainer(for: Observation.self)
        } catch {
            fatalError("Failed to initialize ModelContainer: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        store = DataStore(container: modelContainer)
    }
    
    // MARK: - Methods
    func updateObservations(newObservations: [ObservationWrapper], deletedObservations: [UUID]) {
        Task {
            do {
                try await store.update(newObservations: newObservations, deletedObservations: deletedObservations)
                userDataLogger.debug("Observations updated successfully.")
            } catch {
                userDataLogger.error("Failed to update observations: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
    
}

and is initialized in ContentView with:
let logger = Logger(
    subsystem:
        "com.cyrilzakka.MyApp.ContentView",
    category: "Root View")

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var context
    
    let data = UserData.shared
    
    var body: some View {
        MainView()
            .onAppear {
#if DEBUG
                // Clear HKManager anchor
                UserDefaults.resetDefaults()
                do {
                    // Clear SwiftData container
                    try context.delete(model: Observation.self)
                } catch {
                    
                }
#endif
            }
            .environmentObject(data)
            .task {
                let success = await data.healthKitManager.requestAuthorization()
                if !success { logger.debug("Unable to authenticate HealthKit") }
                await data.healthKitManager.loadLabResults()
            }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
        .environmentObject(UserData.shared)
}

My app is currently crashing with the following error since I think I'm creating two model containers once in MyApp and the other in UserData.
error: CoreData+CloudKit: -[NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate resetAfterError:andKeepContainer:](611): <NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate: 0x3015d14a0> - resetting internal state after error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134422 "CloudKit setup failed because it couldn't register a handler for the export activity. There is another instance of this persistent store actively syncing with CloudKit in this process." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingException=Illegal attempt to register a second handler for activity identifier com.apple.coredata.cloudkit.activity.export.9EBB4062-A03B-4BD3-9222-D079F7C93EBA, NSURL=file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/85683180-384B-4276-88EE-384E50401A37/Library/Application%20Support/default.store, activityIdentifier=com.apple.coredata.cloudkit.activity.export.9EBB4062-A03B-4BD3-9222-D079F7C93EBA, NSLocalizedFailureReason=CloudKit setup failed because it couldn't register a handler for the export activity. There is another instance of this persistent store actively syncing with CloudKit in this process.}

What is the proper way of initializing UserData with a model container while keeping the singleton pattern? Alternatively, should I just create the model container in UserData, but how do I ensure I can use it in all the view in my app?
Update 1:
I ended up doing the following but unsure if it is correct:
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    
    var container: ModelContainer
    
    init() {
        do {
            let config = ModelConfiguration(cloudKitDatabase: .private("iCloud.com.author.MyApp"))
            container = try ModelContainer(for: FHIRObservation.self, configurations: config)
            UserData.shared = UserData(modelContainer: container)
        } catch {
            fatalError("Failed to configure SwiftData container.")
        }
    }
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(UserData.shared) 
        }
        .modelContainer(container)
    }
}


Note, there is no reason to declare class UserData as ObservableObject
since you are not publishing anything. Just use it as a singleton instead of trying to pass it around using .environmentObject(UserData.shared).

Thanks! I've managed to get things working and am able to insert things into the database but as soon as I call context.save() the app crashes with: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key _buffer." @workingdogsupportUkraine

Don't know what other code you have changed, but
note, there is no point in using .environmentObject(UserData.shared).
UserData.shared is a static, you can access it anywhere in your code
just by using UserData.shared. There is no need to pass it around.

@workingdogsupportUkraine got rid of them thank you!

You need to learn extensions, do
extension ModelContainer {

And put your custom logic in there then you can removed UserData
Also you can use .task instead of ObservableObject for your async logic.
